# how to load a page without refreshing the browser in jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp

index.html

```
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $(".navigation a").click(function() {

            $("#content").load($(this).attr("href"));

            return false;
        });

    });
</script>

</head>
 <body>
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="robo.html">Content 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="content2.html">Content 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="content3.html">Content 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
</div>

 conten1.jsp
i have accordian to display
```

if i run content1.jsp the accordian gets displayed,but by clicking  link in index.html file it is not showing acccordian but only the text in accordian

Answer (score 0):

First possible approach (I would *not* recommend it): use frames or iframes -- the ancient solution for this.

Proper solution: use AJAX, with some library like jQuery that knows to execute <script>s and include css files linked by your response HTML.

Answer (score 0):

check your **stylesheet** and **js** is linked with in **head section**.. this may be reason but i'm not sure .you can add those stuffs in loading pages